# Launching Squirrel SQL client on Mac OS

Tags: macos, squirrel-sql

I am Launching SQuirrel SQL on Mac OS X(El Capitan) that has JDK1.8 on it produces an error message saying the JDK-version should be at least 1.6. It then quits. SQL client version is 3.7. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I ran into similar issue and the following change fixed the issue. Open the Application Folder in finder and open the App Package Contents and navigate to Contents/MacOS/. Open the squirrel-sql.sh file and update the value of "SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME" around line 56.

Out of box, the value would be

> SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME=`dirname "$0"`/Contents/Resources/Java

Update this to

> SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME='/Applications/SQuirreLSQL.app/Contents/Resources/Java'

Thanks to https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/1232/#6bc6

Comment: The .sh script has three alternate versions of the command to set the SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME variable. The second one worked for me on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 using Squirrel version 3.8.1.

Comment: Worked on macOs Mojave

Comment: I consider @DaveMulligan 's comment the safer option. Did the trick for me on Mojave 10.14.4 with SQuirreL SQL 3.9.1.

Comment: BTW, on macOS Catalina, modifying anything inside `/Applications/SQuirrelSQL.app` will prevent the app from launching in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

1. Open the squirrel-sql.sh file (`/Applications/SQuirreLSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/squirrel-sql.sh`)
2. Follow the suggests at line 62 to choose the right '`SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME=...`' line by commenting the wrong one and uncommenting the right one. Just like this:

```
##################################################################################################
# CHANGE_HERE
# Mac users are not able which of the three lines below works correctly, see bugs 1287, 1321, 1310.
# Thus if you have problems running SQuirreL on IOS please try out the alternative lines
##################################################################################################    
#    SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME=`dirname "$0"`/Contents/Resources/Java
     SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME=$(echo $ABSPATH | grep -o '^/.*/Contents/')Resources/Java
#    SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME=`dirname "$0"`/../Resources/Java
```

Answer (score 2):

The shell script now comes with Alternative solutions ready. Alternative 2 works for me. Just commented out Alternative 1 and uncommented the 2.

```
#Alternative 1
#SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME=`dirname "$0"`/Contents/Resources/Java

#Alternative 2
SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME=$(echo $ABSPATH | grep -o '^/.*/Contents/')Resources/Java

#Alternative 3
#SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME=`/Applications/SQuirreLSQL.app/Contents/Resources/Java'
```

Open the script file as in @vijay answer.

Comment: This one truly solves the problem. BTW, the shell script is here: `/Applications/SQuirreLSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/squirrel-sql.sh`